# In Quartz 2D, Is it possible to mask an image by removing everything but the color channel you want?

Tags: objective-c, quartz-graphics, masking

So I tried to use the Quartz CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors function, but he only problem is that it masks the color range you are selecting.

I want to mask everything but the color range I am selecting. For instance, I want to show all red colors in a picture but remove the other channels (Green and Blue).

I am doing this in Objective-C and I am a noob so please give me examples :)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use these methods.i found them in one of the SO posts.

```
-(void)changeColor
{
    UIImage *temp23=Image;//Pass your image here
    CGImageRef ref1=[self createMask:temp23];
    const float colorMasking[6] = {1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0};
    CGImageRef New=CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(ref1, colorMasking);
    UIImage *resultedimage=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:New];
    EditImageView.image = resultedimage;
    [EditImageView setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(CGImageRef)createMask:(UIImage*)temp
{


    CGImageRef ref=temp.CGImage;
    int mWidth=CGImageGetWidth(ref);
    int mHeight=CGImageGetHeight(ref);
    int count=mWidth*mHeight*4;
    void *bufferdata=malloc(count);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

    CGContextRef cgctx = CGBitmapContextCreate (bufferdata,mWidth,mHeight, 8,mWidth*4, colorSpaceRef, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst); 

    CGRect rect = {0,0,mWidth,mHeight};
    CGContextDrawImage(cgctx, rect, ref); 
    bufferdata = CGBitmapContextGetData (cgctx);

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, bufferdata, mWidth*mHeight*4, NULL);
    CGImageRef savedimageref = CGImageCreate(mWidth,mHeight, 8, 32, mWidth*4, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo,provider , NULL, NO, renderingIntent);
    CFRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    return savedimageref;
}
```

then call changecolor method on a buttons click event and see the result

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my above problem, Follow the above code of Rahul with some changes to set your own color,

```
-(void)changeColor
{
    UIImage *temp23=Image;//Pass your image here
    CGImageRef ref1=[self createMask:temp23];
    const float colorMasking[6] = {1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0};
    CGImageRef New=CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(ref1, colorMasking);
    UIImage *resultedimage=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:New];
    EditImageView.image = resultedimage;
    [EditImageView setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(CGImageRef)createMask:(UIImage*)temp
{
   CGImageRef ref=temp.CGImage;
   int mWidth=CGImageGetWidth(ref);
   int mHeight=CGImageGetHeight(ref);
   int count=mWidth*mHeight*4;
   void *bufferdata=malloc(count);

   CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
   CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
   CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

   CGContextRef cgctx = CGBitmapContextCreate (bufferdata,mWidth,mHeight, 8,mWidth*4,colorSpaceRef, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast); 
   CGRect rect = {0,0,mWidth,mHeight};  
   CGContextDrawImage(cgctx, rect, ref); 
   CGContextSaveGState(cgctx);  
   CGContextSetBlendMode(cgctx, kCGBlendModeColor); 
   CGContextSetRGBFillColor (cgctx, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
   CGContextFillRect(cgctx, rect);


   bufferdata = CGBitmapContextGetData (cgctx);
   const float colorMasking[6] = {1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0};
   CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, bufferdata, mWidth*mHeight*4, NULL);
   CGImageRef savedimageref = CGImageCreate(mWidth,mHeight, 8, 32, mWidth*4, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo,provider , NULL, NO, renderingIntent);
   CFRelease(colorSpaceRef);
   return savedimageref;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...

I may be missing something, but I don't believe that the provided answers apply to the question.  The second response gets closer to the mark, but it contains spurious code that has little to do with the solution.

The `createMask` method makes a copy of the original image assuming alpha in LSB position. The changeColor performs a masking call that isn't going to do much to an RGB image -- basically only black is going to be masked (i.e, RGB triplets in the range/combinations of (1,1,2) to (3,2,1)).

I am guessing that the red shift that is being observed is due to the parameter

`kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst`

in the line

```
CGContextRef cgctx = CGBitmapContextCreate (bufferdata,mWidth,mHeight, 8,mWidth*4, colorSpaceRef, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
```

due to improper treatment of the alpha channel.  If in the `changeColor` method you modify the block

```
CGImageRef ref1=[self createMask:temp23];
const float colorMasking[6] = {1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0};
CGImageRef New=CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(ref1, colorMasking);
UIImage *resultedimage=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:New];
EditImageView.image = resultedimage;
```

to be

```
CGImageRef ref1=[self createMask:temp23];
UIImage *resultedimage=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];
EditImageView.image = resultedimage;
```

you'll see no difference in the display.  Changing the CGBitmapInfo constant to `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast` should display the image correctly using either of the above code blocks.

The next response gets a bit closer to what the OP asks for, but its in terms of visual effect, not actual data. Here the pertinent code in `createMask` is

```
CGContextRef cgctx = CGBitmapContextCreate (bufferdata,mWidth,mHeight, 8,mWidth*4,colorSpaceRef, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
```

which displays the image correctly, followed by

```
CGContextSetBlendMode(cgctx, kCGBlendModeColor); 
CGContextSetRGBFillColor (cgctx, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextFillRect(cgctx, rect);
```

and then the logic for constructing the image.  The blend logic overlays a red tint on the original image, achieving a similar effect as the misplaced alpha channel in the original response.  This still really is not what the OP asks for, which is to mask one or more channels, not blend colors.

This really amounts to setting the channel values for the colors that are not desired to zero.  Here's an example for returning just the red channel as the OP requests; the assumption is that the format of the pixel is ABGR:

```
- (CGImageRef) redChannel:(CGImageRef)image 
{
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(image);
    NSMutableData* data = (id)CGDataProviderCopyData(provider);

    int width = CGImageGetWidth(image);
    int height = CGImageGetHeight(image);

    [data autorelease];

    // get a mutable reference to the image data
    uint32_t* dwords = [data mutableBytes];

    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < width*height; idx++) {
        uint32_t* pixel = &dwords[idx];
        // perform a logical AND of the pixel with a mask that zeroes out green and blue pixels
        *pixel &= 0x000000ff;
    }

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

    // now create a new image using the masked original data
    CGDataProviderRef iprovider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, dwords, width*height*4, NULL);
    CGImageRef savedimageref = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, width*4, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, iprovider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(iprovider);

    return savedimageref;
}
```

A good summary of bitwise operations can be found [here](http://www.gamedev.net/page/reference/index.html/_/technical/game-programming/bitwise-operations-in-c-r1563).

As is pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487373/how-to-color-mask-in-ctp://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487373/how-to-color-mask-in-c), you may need to change the structure of the mask depending on the LSB/MSB ordering of the bits in the pixel.  This example assumes 32 bit pixels from a standard iPhone PNG.