# how to color mask in c

Tags: c, colors, mask

how do you color mask a 32 bit unsigned integer for the red, green, and blue values

is it like this?
    (color_to_be_masked>>8)

Comment: What do you mean by color mask? The term can be have several valid meanings depending on context. You can provide a link to a page that narrows it down or describe what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you the result you want:

```
short red = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
short green = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
short blue = (color) & 0xFF;
```

Comment: +1, though I find it clearer (and very very very minimally faster) to shift the constants.

Comment: Why is it faster to shift the constants? I just claimed the opposite in my answer ...

Comment: @Santiago Lezica: I'm sorry, that just doesn't make any sense to me. You're still going to need the shifts at run-time, the difference is just whether you write (rgba & 0xff0000) >> 16 or (rgba >> 16) & 0xff. It's always a bitwise and with a constant right-hand argument, in the latter case it's just smaller which might take less space in the instruction encoding.

Comment: @Santiago Lezica: the code "var & (const >> 16)" makes absolutely no sense at all in this context.

Comment: Nope, you're right, no shifting constants. As you said below, it wouldn't leave the value in the lower byte.

Answer (score 0):

"It depends", namely on which bits are which color.

Often they're mapped "backwards", so that Red is in the lower-most bits, green in the "middle", and blue on top (sometimes followed by alpha, if that is being used).

Assuming 8 bits per component, you would have:

```
uint32_t abgr = 0x80eeccaa;  /* Or whatever. */
const uint8_t red = abgr & 0xff;
const uint8_t green = (abgr >> 8) & 0xff;
const uint8_t blue = (abgr >> 16) & 0xff;
const uint8_t alpha = (abgr >> 24) & 0xff;
```

If you're really using "rgba" component order, swap the above around:

```
uint32_t rgba = 0xaaccee80;  /* Or whatever. */
const uint8_t red = (abgr >> 24) & 0xff;
const uint8_t green = (abgr >> 16) & 0xff;
const uint8_t blue = (abgr >> 8) & 0xff;
const uint8_t alpha = abgr & 0xff;
```

Note that I shift before I mask, that's nice since it makes the constant that forms the mask smaller which is potentially more efficient.

Comment: @Santiago Lezica: as I commented in another answer, I don't believe you at all. Perhaps you should post an answer of your own, illustrating the technique you suggest.

Comment: @Santiago Lezica: I'm not "ranting". :) I'm just worried about answer quality on this site, and also intrigued since I've spent quite some time thinking about this masking code, and you seem to know something I don't. However, I believe you're wrong. Your suggested code green = agbr & (0xff << 8) does not end up with the green bits in the lower bits of 'green', which was the intent in my code.

Comment: Look at that, you're right, it doesn't. I was thinking bitmasks, not values. Let's delete the previous comments, most people won't read through this bible of comments to decide.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the format. If you only want to keep the red, and the colors are stored nibble-wise RGBA `RRGGBBAA`, then `color & 0xFF000000` will mask out all the other colors. If you want to know the red value for that same format, `(color >> 24) & 0xFF` will get it.

Answer (score 0):

If you cast to char or uint8_t afterwards, it works like you said.

Otherwise you need to add a  `&0xff`as well, or you'll have the remaining bits too (for all but the most significant color). So, something like `(color >> multiple_of_8) &0xff`.

Important detail: There is RGBA and BGRA component ordering, and there are different endiannesses on different CPUs. You must know which one you have to get it right (e.g. Windows GDI is BGRA).