# Open CV water colour filter. (iterating through the pixels of an image)

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to follow this pseudocode to implement a water colour filter in Open CV.
http://supercomputingblog.com/graphics/oil-painting-algorithm/

I've previously achieved the effect using this method in javascript with a canvas because I could iterate over the pixels however I'm not sure how to do that with Open CV.

```
Mat im = imread(...); //input image
Mat paint; // output after processing
for(int i = 0; i < im.rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < im.cols; j++) //for each pixel
    {
        //here I need a reference to the pixel colour from im
    }
}
```

I tried to use:

```
im.at<uchar>(i,j)
```

However this is giving me values around 350 for the most part which suggested to me that it's the cumulation of the rgb channels (a multi-channel array I think). So I tried to split it like this:

```
vector<Mat> three_channels;
split(im, three_channels);
```

But it just gives me the same value 3 times. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just accessing them, thusly:

```
int r = im.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x)[0];
int g = im.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x)[1];
int b = im.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x)[2];
```

as was mentioned in the answer to a previous question.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the time, colors are just 8-bit combined rather than in an array, so you need masks to manipulate them.

```
short red = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
short green = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
short blue = (color) & 0xFF;
```

(via [how to color mask in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487373/how-to-color-mask-in-c))

Comment: Thank you for your reply, sorry I'm not sure I really understand. What am I feeding into the color placeholder / variable? 

`im.at<uchar>(i,j)`? as per my example? I tried that and I was getting reasonable values in the blue channel but just 0's for red and green. Any ideas?

Comment: If I remember correctly, you would need to fetch your colors using your im.at(i,j) which would get you a 32-bit (or 24 ?) pixel.

Then you need to put the corrected pixel in a new Matrix object, written afterwards in your image.

However the fact that your pixel is always 350 might be another problem.

Comment: So if I store the value as Vec3b color = im.at<Vec3b>(Point(j,i)); I get a vector 3 with the red blue and green channels but how do I access that? I tried color.val[0] to get the red but that just gave me the original 300+ value again.